# What is an access link on a stack frame?

Tags: c, callstack

I had about [access links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack#Lexically_nested_routines) from wikipedia but I could not get a clear picture of what access links are and how they are different from return address of any function. Can someone explain in brief what an access link is and why its necessary on a call stack ?

Comment: As long as you are using C, there are no access links.

Comment: Wikipedia says if we have nested subroutines we will have access links, and C supports nested subroutines, so we should be having access links in C, right ?

Comment: They are not supported in C. Your compiler may have them as an extension, but then they are an extension to C, not C.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would actually meet such paradigm in `Pascal` or `Java`, for example, not in `C`.

For example, in Java, you could declare:

```
void func1() {
     int outer = 2;
     int func2() {
        int inner = 3;
        return inner+outer;
     }
     int result = func2();
}
```

At the end of `func1` execution, the `result` variable would contain 5 that is a sum of locally defined variables `outer` and `inner`.

The `access link` serves exactly this purpose - to pass the 'pointer' to the actual outer scope into the inner function.

The `gcc` compiler has [Nested Functions extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html) that is not a part of the `C` standard as n.m mentioned

Comment: I copied the above code and ran in C, it compiled and gave the correct output, why do you say this is not supported in C ?

Comment: what `C` compiler do you use?

Comment: I use gcc, I was running with `gcc -std=gnu99 -g -Wall -m32 filename.c`

Comment: I am able to compile and get the output

Comment: Anyway, as @n.m mentioned and I pointed in the answer this is not a part of the `C` standard. If you want your code to be portable then you have to avoid any extensions.

Comment: @vikkyhacks You need to compile with -Wpedantic to get warnings about extensions. http://ideone.com/nwSR18